# Echo data in same form after submitting

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, spry

I have a simple html form, which is included in a Spry Tabbed Panel.
So, i would like to know, is it possible to submit that form, and only that form in the Panel, and then echo the submitted data back in the correct fields.

The echo part is not a problem doing it on a different page, or redirect after submitting, but my issue comes in with the other forms that should/can not be cleared if this one is submitted.

A hint in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

see code below:

(i know that the form action should not direct to a different file, but that is just how I've been using it until now...)

```
    <form action="caller_upd.php" method="post" name="contact" >
  <table width="200" border="0">
  <?php 
  $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
  ?>
    <tr>
    <td width="68">Title</td>
    <td width="4">:</td>
    <td width="144"><select name="title" id="title">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled"</option>
      <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
      <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
      <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
    </select></td>
    <td width="6">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="53">Number</td>
    <td width="3">:</td>
    <td width="301"><input style="color:rgb(255,0,0);" autofocus="autofocus"  type="text" name="contactnr" id="contactnr" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Surname</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sname" id="sname" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nature of Call</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><select name="type" id="type">
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected"></option>
      <option value="Domestic">Domestic</option>
      <option value="MVA">MVA</option>
      <option value="Assult">Assult</option>
      <option value="Padestrian">Padestrian</option>
      <option value="Transfer">Transfer</option>
      <option value="Private">Private</option>
</select></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Nr of Patients:</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><select name="nop" id="nop">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10+">10+</option>
    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Location</td>
    <td><label for="location"></label></td>
    <td colspan="5"><input name="location" type="text" id="location" size="50" /> <?php if (!empty($location)){ ?><a href="street_map.php" target="_blank">Show Map</a><?php } else { } ; ?></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Comments:</td>
    <td colspan="6"><textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="70" rows="5"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7" class="form"><input type="submit" name="submit"  id="submit" value="Update" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe with PHP_SELF instead of  caller_upd.php may do the trick, more info here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: `<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['fname']?$_POST['fname']:''; ?>"/>` hope you can do for others.Assume you are not doing header redirect

Comment: Thank you @ShaifulIslam. i will try the code and get back to you! Thanks fir the effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the post value exists, and if so either select the option or put the value in the input element...

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="contact" >
    <table width="200" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="68">Title</td>
            <td width="4">:</td>
            <td width="144"><select name="title" id="title">
                    <option value="Mr" <?php if(isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] == "Mr") echo "selected"; ?>>Mr</option>
                    <option value="Ms" <?php if(isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] == "Ms") echo "selected"; ?>>Ms</option>
                    <option value="Dr" <?php if(isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] == "Dr") echo "selected"; ?>>Dr</option>
                </select></td>
            <td width="6">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="53">Number</td>
            <td width="3">:</td>
            <td width="301"><input style="color:rgb(255,0,0);" autofocus="autofocus"  type="text" name="contactnr" id="contactnr" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['contactnr'])) echo $_POST['contactnr']; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['fname'])) echo $_POST['fname']; ?>" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Surname</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="sname" id="sname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['sname'])) echo $_POST['sname']; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but i get the following error when trying your example as posted above:

Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in C:\xampp\htdocs\...

Comment: @Boeta sorry, I fixed it. Try again.

Comment: I realized the error in the code, thank you! will be back soon with the verdict.

Comment: Okay, so it works great, i figured both. but, the submit key, is now linked to a specific function.... creating the DB entry, and i would like to update the form info thats echo'd should needs be, but then the submit button has the same Fx, causing a duplicate entry in the DB

Comment: @Boeta, one problem per thread please. Mark my answer as correct and open a new question. Show the JS code in your new question.